# What is the best way in sql to select 3 users from data in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I am currently working on a site that contains a loan application, in that loan application there is a primary borrower and then there can be up to 2 co-borrowers. What I've done is created a `loanSubmission` table that contains a `uid1`, `uid2` and `uid3` column which represents the `user id` and then the number of the user. The `id` of the user is stored in each one of these columns and the users full information is stored within the `users` table.

I need to select three users from the data in another table. Is there a way to achieve this using a join or would I have to use sub queries? I've never had to join multiple users based on info from another table so any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Select 3 users": *Vague & broad*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not quite sure how to explain its pretty simple. I need to get up to 3 users information based on data stored in `loanSubmission` table. The users id's are stored in the `loanSubmission` table and I need to join the `loanSubmission` table with the 3 users information such as first name, last name, etc. 

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks. As for the JOINS, I wish I could help you with that, but I haven't quite fully grasped those (yet). However, if you want to limit it to 3, you can try using `LIMIT 3` and sort using `ASC` in ascending order. `GROUP BY` is another option; I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you use aliases to join to the same table multiple times:

```
SELECT user1.id, user2.id, user3.id FROM loanSubmission
  INNER JOIN users user1 ON user1.id = loanSubmission.uid1
  INNER JOIN users user2 ON user2.id = loanSubmission.uid2
  INNER JOIN users user3 ON user3.id = loanSubmission.uid3
```

or depending on if you want blank users(which you probably do)

```
SELECT user1.id, user2.id, user3.id FROM loanSubmission
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users user1 ON user1.id = loanSubmission.uid1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users user2 ON user2.id = loanSubmission.uid2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users user3 ON user3.id = loanSubmission.uid3
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much this helps a lot i figured it was possible but never had to do it before!

Comment: Great, yet I'm just wondering what you'll have to deal with, if and when you start getting 50, 100+ users, should that be the case in the future. @TomBird

Comment: @Fred-ii- The most users I'll have to view in one single instance would be 4. Are you meaning in relation to the sizes of the database or the number of users I would have to join?

Comment: @TomBird In relation to the code required for additional joins, yes.

Comment: I haven't really thought about that issue yet, is there a more optimized way I should accomplish this? I was also contemplating how I would run a search if someone wanted to search for a specific application based on any of the three borrowers and that seems like it maybe complex

Comment: Yeah, Generally I think that you would use a mapping table, that way you only need one join.

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyJulz I'll look up some info on mapping tables!